# Error con heroku en node: Failed lookup view in views derectory

Tags: nodejs, heroku

Tengo una app web que funciona bien en local pero en al subirla a heroku salia lo siguiente en los logs

`2017-01-01T00:30:57.874896+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to lookup view "notFound" in views directory "/app/views"
2017-01-01T00:30:57.874919+00:00 app[web.1]:     at EventEmitter.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:579:17)
2017-01-01T00:30:57.874920+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)
2017-01-01T00:30:57.874921+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports.notFound (/app/routes/index.js:31:7)
2017-01-01T00:30:57.874922+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-01-01T00:30:57.874922+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
2017-01-01T00:30:57.874923+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2017-01-01T00:30:57.874923+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-01-01T00:30:57.874924+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
2017-01-01T00:30:57.874924+00:00 app[web.1]:     at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:349:14)
2017-01-01T00:30:57.874925+00:00 app[web.1]:     at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)`

Investigue un poco y vi que tenia que poner esto en archivo principal de node

```
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views'(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
```

Pero eso a mi seguia sin funcionarme por lo que fui a la documentación de node y encontré la solución que se las comparto abajo por si alguien tiene el mismo problema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En lugar de esto:

```
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views'(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
```

puse esto:

```
var path=require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(process.cwd() + '/views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd() + '/public')));
```

Ademas de que mi carpeta para las vistas se llamaba "Views" y lo renombre a minusculas (views), y ya funciono correctamente